# How to put a placeholder on jquery ui combobox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I look at [jquery ui combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) but i could not find it.Where can i right placeholder in source code.

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add an ID to your input
and run this code in javascript

```
$("#yourID").attr("placeholder", "Your Text Here");
```

Comment: Actually, this wont work since the Jquery UI Combo box uses a **select** tag and **select** tags do not accept the placeholder attribute.

Comment: I'll give you the upvote buddy,  this works using prop as well.

Answer (score 15):

I made this code for JQueryUI v1.10.2 - 2013-04-17

HTML code:

```
<select class="combobox" placeholder="123">
 <option>...</option>
 ...
</select>
```

JS code:

```
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
            .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
            .insertAfter( this.element );

        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
        this.input.attr("placeholder", this.element.attr('placeholder'));
    },
});

$(function() {
    $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="test" name="test">
  <option value=""></option> <!-- clear default value-->
  <option value="1">text 1</option>
  <option value="2">text 2</option>
</select>

<script>
 $('#test').combobox();
 $('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('width','300px')
 $('.ui-autocomplete-input').attr('placeholder','Select a value')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do even a little bit simpler based on jquery ui 1.10.3:
Find `var input = $("<input>")` in combobox file and add attribute placeholder:

```
.attr("placeholder", select.attr("title"))
```

And just use title attribute in select :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple placeholder for `input`.
 You can use html5 `placeholder` or try to do it yourself.

`<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">`

The only problem is that `placeholder` **doesn't work on Internet Explorer**.
But you can easy find a workaround for it.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/q64xx/): using placeholder
[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/q64xx/2/): crossbrowser workaround